# Virtualbox vboxmanage clone does not show up in virtual machine list

Tags: bash, command-line, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine that I am cloning with the command line interface to virtualbox like so:

```
vboxmanage clonevm origVM --name origClone
```

However, the clone is added to the directory `~/Virtualbox\ Vms` but not 'imported' into the list of virtual machines accessible by Virtualbox. By this I mean that it is not present in `vboxmanage list vms` or in the graphical frontend.

Moreover, I have looked into import functionality, but this appears to be exclusive to bundled virtual machines of the filetypes `{ovf,ova}`.

My general  goal is to copy a virtual machine from a template `vm.ovf` which has already been imported to be used in a multiuser environment. For instance, user1 has vm1 cloned from `vm.ovf` and user2 has vm2 cloned from `vm.ovf` and they can both work on their own vm "branches."

Answer (score 3):

Did it.

```
$ vboxmanage registervm ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/origClone/origClone.vbox
```